# How to define 2d array input/output which has different width?

Tags: system-verilog

In my previous module, I used parameter to define 2d array input/output like the code below:

```
parameter AXI_PORT_NUM   = 5;
parameter AXI_ADDR_WIDTH = 32;

input [AXI_PORT_NUM-1:0][AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0]  axaddr_m;
```

This code has the defect that the address in each port has the same width `AXI_ADDR_WIDTH`. I think 2d parameter should be used as below:

```
parameter AXI_PORT_NUM   = 5;
parameter AXI_ADDR_WIDTH [AXI_PORT_NUM-1:0] = '{32,33,32,32,33};
```

But, I am stuck at how to define the input `axaddr_m` using `AXI_PORT_NUM` and the new 2d parameter `AXI_ADDR_WIDTH`.

Would someone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are sets of signals that have the same bit width.  Since you have signals which have different bit widths (32 and 33), they can not be the part of the same array.  You can use 2 sets of arrays:

```
parameter AXI_PORT_NUM1   = 2;
parameter AXI_ADDR_WIDTH1 = 32;
parameter AXI_PORT_NUM2   = 2;
parameter AXI_ADDR_WIDTH2 = 33;

input [AXI_PORT_NUM1-1:0][AXI_ADDR_WIDTH1-1:0]  axaddr_m1;
input [AXI_PORT_NUM2-1:0][AXI_ADDR_WIDTH2-1:0]  axaddr_m2;
```

Any of these parameters can be overridden for a module instance to accommodate different numbers of ports or address widths.

If you have more signals that use the same parameters, you can  group them into a parameterized `interface`.

Comment: But if there are 3 different width values of axaddr, 2 sets of arrays would be not enough. What I'm seeking for is a method that can handle the situation of no matter how many axi ports, and whatever the width of axaddr in each port. Do you have any good idea?